# 'plt.contourf' with given number of levels in logscale

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

With these lines, currently I'm having this kind of figure.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, 50, cmap=cm.get_cmap('jet')) # linear mapping
#cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, 50, locator=ticker.LogLocator(), cmap=cm.get_cmap('jet')) # log mapping
cbar = fig.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I want to plot this in Log scale, so if I activate the commented line, I get this kind of result which seems to ignore 'levels' argument which is set to '50'.

[image]

I've reached this post ([Python matplotlib contour plot logarithmic color scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748076/python-matplotlib-contour-plot-logarithmic-color-scale)), but I am pretty sure that there is a way in which I do not have to set all the values of levels manually.

Does anyone has a comment, or any other handy python functions for logarithmatic contour plot with many levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the number of levels as a integer doesn't work for logscale but you can easily set the values with `np.logspace(np.log10(z.min()),np.log10(z.max()), 50)`. Matplotlib 3.3.3 seems to have some difficulties in correctly formatting the colorbar ticks in this case, so you need to manually adjust them a bit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker, cm
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 100)
y = np.linspace(-2.0, 2.0, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z1 = np.exp(-(X)**2 - (Y)**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X * 10)**2 - (Y * 10)**2)
z = Z1 + 50 * Z2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

n_levels = 50
cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, z, 
                 np.logspace(np.log10(z.min()),np.log10(z.max()), n_levels), 
                 locator=ticker.LogLocator(), 
                 cmap=cm.jet
                 )

cbar = fig.colorbar(cs)
cbar.locator = ticker.LogLocator(10)
cbar.set_ticks(cbar.locator.tick_values(z.min(), z.max()))
cbar.minorticks_off()
```

[image]

Comment: this only works for matplotlib < 3.5.0, it's broken in versions 3.5.0 - at least 3.5.3.